# List of categories of Design patterns which exists?

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to understand the design patterns and I came across lot of them, so I am bit confused on where to start, what to really focus on, what is that which really matters and what to really study.

For example, refer to screen shot below:

[image]

Can anyone please guide me how to start learning the design patterns and which one really matters.

Comment: Are you trying to learn the general purpose of design patterns or are you trying to tackle a specific problem and are searching for the matching design pattern to apply ?

Comment: Here is my contribution: http://www.thejavageek.com/design-patterns/

Comment: @Veverke: I am trying to learn the design patterns and eventually want to apply in Enterprise application development (mainly in Java); but I want to start with the basics ; but daunted to see so many design patterns. Hence seeking some guidance on the approach and what really matters in real life.

Comment: I originally posted an answer where I stated, from my experience, categorizing them into their corresponding types makes it a lot easier - but I see you already have that.

Comment: I think wiki's page or any other google 'design patterns' 10 first results does a good job in giving a general explanation of what a design pattern is supposed to be. If that is not enough, do check the book @dstar55 mentions, it's indeed a good one. I still insist that wiki's page is good enough, the first paragraphs, before the table of contents, do outline what a DP is. The rest is about grouping them according to similiarities/aspects they share in common with each other.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different kinds of patterns as you have discovered. [Gof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) caused and explosion of patterns. The Gof patterns *are* design patterns. Most of the others are *not*.

There is a sort of a taxonomy [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

You may want to just start with [enterprise integration patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/), or [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/).

Also there are these [Posa's](http://wiki.c2.com/?PatternOrientedSoftwareArchitecture).

The [J2ee patterns](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/) are somewhat similar to the Poeaa stuff. The enterprise integration patterns are higher level and deal more with messaging.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Are J2EE design pattern different from POEA? And are all patterns built on-top-of "GoF" patterns. If you elucidate a bit more would be of great help.

Comment: Generally design patterns are not language specific.  That is, the design patterns mentioned in the above books are all specific to object-oriented design / development specific.  Therefore any language that supports object-oriented development could be employed for the design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [**G**ang **O**f **F**our design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).
Creational, Structural & Behavioral are covered in GoF patterns. Later you can learn specific/advanced patterns(ORM, Concurency, J2EE, ...).